# Stacks for Android

Tags: app, android

[image] [image]
[image]

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxscheglov.stackoverflow

Features:

- Supports all the sites in the Stack Exchange network
- Easy access to over a million questions and answers, on topics from programming to cooking
- View full questions and answers including comments and images
- Sort questions by date, votes, popularity.
- Search for topics that interest you by the title, body text or phrase
- Browse tags

To get Stacks, either:

- Search the Android Market on your phone for "Stacks"
- Go to the Android Market page
  Open the URL market://details?id=com.maxscheglov.stacks on your phone

QR code:

[image]

Comment: When was this released?  I'm in the midst of making my own StackExchange app for Android.

Comment: I think there is a debug echoing back any search terms as a URL. I cannot search for my own user or any questions. All that happens is a dialog is raised with a URL containing the search parameters. 4/27/2011

Comment: @penguin359 Me too.  Mine's almost done.  Looks like there's going to be a lot of competition.  I haven't downloaded this one yet but the screenshots look good.

Comment: @Dan I look forward to seeing yours.  Yes, Stacks looks prettier than mine right now.

Comment: I released it this monday, April 25th. Look forward to seeing yours apps, guys :)

Comment: The QR-Code does not work... The App could not be found by market.
I installed it from the desktopmarket, now I am searchin a way to log into my Account...

Comment: Great application, though I have a few things to say. First, when searching for my account (with Jon being a common username and all) the user search only loads 20 users. Also, when searching for questions, it seems there cannot be a space in the search, otherwise it just pops up a notice with the search URL. With that being said though, it's a great application. Please continue developing it.

Comment: A few other things: Questions should have author information on them, as well as answers. I'm also unable to click on users names in comments - it just underlines them. Also while messing around with the search, replacing spaces in my search with %20 does indeed work.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the links to the source and install website went dead. I'm keeping this for reference in case someone else gets inspired by this and creates a new fresh script or app.